# The usage of the "the"

Tags: grammar, syntax, emphasis

Which of the following is grammatically correct:

"Other cell products may depend on concentrations of ... ?"

"Other cell products may depend on **the** concentrations of ... ?"

If both are, is there really a difference of emphasis? The kind of read the same, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those sentences are grammatically correct. The difference would seem to be one of emphasis, as you suggest. The second example assigns more importance to the concentrations, implying that either:

- they have been mentioned before in the piece of writing, or
- they will be mentioned again